# Bonferroni correction of bootstrap generated p values

Tags: p-value, bootstrap, bonferroni

I have run a multiple regression analysis with 900 independent variables and bootstrapped this analysis 1000 times, with replacement, to generate bootstrap p values. When I looked at the results, I notice that I have several significant p values, but I know that some of these could be false positives, being significant simply because of running the bootstrap so many times (multiple testing). my question is, can you use Bonferroni correction on bootstrap generated p values to account for the multiple testing? How exactly would you go about this?

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think there's some confusion here: multiple comparisons is a problem when you are testing multiple hypotheses, i.e. each of the 900 variables. So you should correct for doing 900 tests. It is NOT an issue of running too many bootstrap samples; more bootstrap samples only gives you more precisely calculated p-values.

Comment: @Cliff AB. Yes, I have to admit that I was a little confused by it. I get it now. Thanks for that.